# JSON response react native Post method problem

Tags: json, react-native, post

I am facing a strange problem, I am using Nexmo to verify number, and I am sending a post method

```
fetch('http://monasabat-app.com/basta_app/sign_up.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: formBody
}).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => { 
              const ss1 = responseJson.status[0]
              console.log(ss1)
              let success = 'success'
              if(ss1.status === success){
                alert(ss1.status)
                this.props.navigation.navigate('verNum',{
                  uid:ss1.uid,
                  phone:this.state.phone,
                  name:this.state.name,
                  emai:this.state.email
                })


              }else{
                alert(ss1.status)
              }
```

The sign up info(formBody) is successfully stored in the database but it doesn't navigate to the verNum screen neither alert the ss1.status but if the response is not success it does alert ss1.status in the else part (num is already registered) so I guess the problem is in the if condition part but the strange thing it does work sometimes and it doesn't some other times with a warning Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1).

My JSON response

```
{
    "status": [
        {
            "status": "success",
            "uid": "99"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the `this.props` and `this.state` is accessible inside the promise.

If not before fetch create a variable that takes the value of `this`

Example `let self = this;`

then

```
this.props.navigation.navigate
```

would become

```
self.props.navigation.navigate.
```

Comment: it did work for me the first time but when i tried to register another user it didn't navigate to the verNum screen and it showed Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: the problem is not with the navigation cause even the alert(ss1.status) which is before the navigation is not getting called

Comment: I found the problem, its in the Nexmo verfication, its throwing an exception, thank you though